# Как скомпилировать release в Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, c++

Не могу понять, как скомпилировать realease, что бы приложением можно было свободно пользоваться и оно не требовало библиотек Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте статическую линковку (например, [тык](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137233/) и [тык](http://www.learnqt.com/how-to-learn-qt/qt-install/qt-443-mingw-qt-creator-and-static-linking/) - первое, что выдал гугл), что, конечно же, скажется на конечном размере полученного бинарника.

В случае динамической линковки, ваше приложение в любом случае будет требовать динамические библиотеки Qt (.dll или .so).

Ну и не забывайте, что LGPL не позволяет статическую линковку. А в случае выбора GPL вы должны будете предоставить исходные коды своего ПО. Или приобретайте коммерческую лицензию Qt.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, динамическая линковка чревата лишь увеличением размера программы в итоге?

Comment: Да. Ну или уменьшением, ведь необходимые библиотеки могут уже быть установленными в системе другим приложением.

Answer (score 0):

Release/Debug не помогут - нужна статическая сборка с Qt.

P.S. насколько я помню, собирать webkit статически нельзя по лицензионным соображениям.

Comment: То есть мне нужно еще и вместе с установкой приложения устанавливать библиотеки на клиентскую машину?

Comment: если нужен webkit, то да. Особого смысла нет использовать статич. линковку с Qt, особенно если это windows.